# Send E-mail without using SMTP in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

My website uses ASP.NET to send emails, but my school's network administrator has blocked the SMTP port and services. After I visited the p2p forums I found a suggestion to use web service to send email, have you any suggestion which website would provide web service for sending emails?

I tried to use System.Web.Mail.MailMessage class to send the emails through my program, but it also fail. Anyone can help me to solve this problem? I need your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/developers).

They offer a webservice and you can send up to 200 emails a day with a free account.

They have code samples for several languages: https://github.com/sendgrid

Answer (score 0):

I think Email sending with ASp.net has nothing to do with blocking of your smtp port and service of school.

You can use gmail's smtp server for sening email in your application/

```
 SMTP URL HOST : smtp.gmail.com,
 IS SSL Enabled : true,
 PORT: 465,
 USERId:your_username@gmail.com,
 Password: Your_Password
```

Answer (score 0):

Use *Gmail, Yahoo* or other Email providers to send a mail.

Please refer my answer @CodeProject - [sending email to gmail from asp.net](http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/321575/sending-email-to-gmail-from-asp-net#answer3), if you want to use *Gmail*.

Also follow - [Send Email from Yahoo, Gmail, Hotmail (C#)](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/520998/Send-Email-from-Yahoo-Gmail-Hotmail-Csharp).

Answer (score 0):

Well that depends, if you are talking about the SMTP port of your network, then you can still use Gmail, Yahoo, Outlook or other ports, all you will be needing will be just a username and password alongwith the port (that must be 25) and the server address (for gmail it is smtp.gmail.com).

But if you are talking about **Sending emails without using SMPT**. Its not possible, with or without ASP.NET.

However, you can try using SmtpSettings for ASP.NET.

There are some other issue too. Please checked that the SmtpServer that you are using (gmail, yahoo etc) are allowed, because if they are blocked too, you would have to search for something new.

And yes, there are some other servers too. Like free email providers that would also let you use 200emails/day for free or something like that. You can check that out.

You mentioned you are using **System.Web.Mail.MailMessage**, here is an msdn blog post about setting the Smtp for that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mail.mailmessage.aspx